# js event looping on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, foreach

i have this div in my homepage.php file:

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
   </div class="post>
            <div class="options">
                <div class="option"></div>
                <div class="option"></div>
                <div class="option"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="none editanddelete">
                <button type="button" class="edit">edit</button>
                <button type="button" class="delete">delete</button>

            </div>
            <div class="imageandname">
                <img src="<?php echo $post->user_image ?>">
                <div class="username"><?php echo $post->username ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="post_body">
                <?php echo $post->post_body ?><br>

            </div>
   </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

the $posts is array that is coming from database through controller and each time i publish a post, the body will add new div like above with the data needed from the $post array, now as shown above, the child div with class "editanddelete" is hidden by giving class "none" which is display:none;
now with javascript i want to make an event where when i click on the child div with class="options", it toggles the "none" class of the child div with class="editanddelete", like the following:

```
post = document.querySelector('.post');
options = post.querySelector('.options');
editanddelete = options.querySelector('.editanddelete');

options.addEventListener('click', () => {
   editanddelete.classList.toggle('none');
})
```

when i execute this code, it works fine on the first post (div) that is dynamically created, but when i add another post, the event will not work on the second post div, i tried to use querySelectorAll and loop "options" classes  that will be created dynamically, but it just does not work as expected and the event affects other divs, what i want is to make the event for all divs, every div on it's own

Comment: Sure, you never tell 'work with 3rd .post element'.

Comment: not only the 2nd and 3rd. rather all post divs that are dynamically created by looping the $posts array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to work with the same `.editanddelete` element as `.options` is clicked.

JS code could be like

```
var options = document.querySelector('.options');

// here maybe would be for cycle over options (I can't test it now)
options.addEventListener('click', () => {
   this.parentNode.querySelector('.editanddelete').classList.toggle('none');
})
```

Comment: this is just the same as my code, where  **editanddelete = options.querySelector('.editanddelete');** is the same as **this.parentNode.querySelector('.editanddelete')**

Comment: it gives the same result where it only works at first div that is dynamically created, and not other divs

Comment: As I wrote in my code comment, maybe there has to be for loop around (to iterate over options collection).  Just add it.

Comment: oh my God, finally it worked, i still don't understand how, but thanks mate